# Создание AutoCompleteTextView внутри кастомного Menu

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

Как создать  AutoCompleteTextView внутри кастомного меню?

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в ActionBar или Toolbar?

Comment: @pavlofff А чем они отличаются ?

Comment: здесь нужно вам ответить, что используете **вы**:  ActionBar, Toolbar или что то еще в качестве кастомного меню.

Comment: @pavlofff В ToolBar !